# sending http requests inside loop

Tags: sql, node.js, httprequest

I'm actually facing a problem with my javascript code executed with node.js i need to send http requests in a loop. 
The problem i have is that, it will just loop and not do the http request.

Comment: Not a node.js guy, but I did notice inset into myTable  vs. INSERT

Comment: Shouldn't that sleep be inside the while?

Comment: edited that was copy paste mistake.